# On Mac OS X over time I get multiple instances of TextMate running. Is there any way to prevent this?

Tags: macos, textmate

On Mac OS X over time I get multiple instances of TextMate running. Is there any way to prevent this?

edit: i'm launching from the command line alias, and from the finder. yes, i only have one copy installed on the hard drive.

**More Details:**
Recreation: Textmate is open, I've launched it via clicking on a file in the finder. Then I run this script to open my hosts file with textmate:

```
#!/bin/bash
`/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS/TextMate /etc/hosts`
```

After that I have two instances open. They both show up in task switcher, and they both show up in the dock. When I go to the dock and do "show in finder" they both point to TextMate.app in the applications folder. and, @romainl, yes, there are two instances in the activity monitor.

Is that script the culprit?

Comment: Would be helpful if you knew what was causing them to be launched...are you sure you only have one copy of it installed on disk?

Comment: there is just one. i thought it would prevent this automatically.

Comment: It should be.  There's a mitigating circumstance here.  When the second one opens, right click on it in the Dock and go to `options`->`show in finder`, just as a paranoia check.  Are you opening protected files? Its hard to tell you how to prevent it when you haven't given us enough information to identify the cause...we need to start there.

Comment: I suggest you delete the `mate` utility and reinstall it again from *TextMate » Help » Terminal Usage…* to make sure it's up to date and created using the supported way.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this on snow leopard via the command line, what os x release are you using?

Comment: @cwd how do you know there are multiple TextMate instances running? Do you see more than one TextMate icon in the dock? If you search for "TextMate" in Activity Monitor.app do you get more than one entry in the list? TextMate, like most Mac apps, has no default workspace and, like most Mac apps is not supposed to have multiple instances.

Comment: @romainl You can probably reproduce it by entering `open -n -a TextMate` in Terminal.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, I didn't know about the `-n` switch, thanks. Anyway, it doesn't work, I still have a single TextMate process/icon and we still don't have much information from the OP. I wonder if what he thinks are "instances" aren't simply "windows". You can use `mate` to open multiple files in a scratch project but using `mate` again won't add the new files to the previous "project" and, instead, create a new scratch project, giving — possibly — the illusion that `n` TextMates are running. But, then again, we are a bit in the dark, here.

Comment: @romainl I meant to edit the comment, but was distracted -- I forgot that TextMate resists the `-n` switch somehow, just as e.g. iTunes. You're right, let's wait for more info from @cwd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That script directly starts the executable.

Use the following instead:

`open -a TextMate /etc/hosts`

This doesn't launch a new instance, unless explicitly told so by using the `-n` switch (which TextMate ignores anyway).

Comment: Seriously, what do you expect? *You are launching a new instance of TextMate* that happens to open the specified file directly after launching. *Of course* you have two instances running afterwards.

Comment: You don't need to capitalize `TextMate`, `open -a textmate` works just as well and is more finger-friendly. The official `mate` utility mentioned by @Daniel Beck is even better and makes less typing.

Comment: I also found that using this command prevents a new instance, it is using the command line alias tool: `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /etc/hosts`